# build error wso2is 5.1.0

Tags: maven, build, wso2-identity-server

I tried to build wso2 Identity Server 5.1.0 from source, but I'm getting the following error:

org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.server.feature:zip:4.2.6 in http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of wso2-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced

I verified manually and couldn't find the resource either. I hope someone in wso2 can help me.